# Ubuntu 12.04 key bindings not working in IntelliJ Idea 12

Tags: 12.04, unity, java, ide, intellij

I've installed the latest version of IntelliJ Idea Community Edition (12.0.1) and I have problems with key bindings there. I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with Unity.

None of them, where a letter is involved (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd>) are working in Idea. And they are working in all other applications.

I can copy/paste text in Idea with mouse and it shows me that key bindings for this are <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd>/<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd>, but they are just not working.

I have no idea what is the problem, so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't seem to have enough reputation to comment, so I'm commenting via answer: I have *exactly* the same problem, using Intellij 12.1 on Ubuntu 13.04. Neither Ctl nor Alt work, although they work fine in other programs.

Answer (score 0):

Check the key bindings in Ubuntu and Idea. Some key-constellations do overlap. The system prefers Ubuntu keybindings.

Comment: How can we easily decide to prefer idea instead of ubuntu?